# Overflowing and Scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation, scroll

I am trying a Simple Drawer Side Menu for my navigation on one of my test websites. Here is the link, http://iamaaron.com/alpha/.

When you click on the menu it pushes everything to else to the right, as expected... But, when I open the menu on a touch based device, I am still allowed to scroll to the right to see the rest of the content. How can I disable scrolling on the rest of the pages (excluding the side menu) when the side menu is open?

jQuery Code:

```
    jQuery('#simple-menu').toggleClick(function() {
        jQuery("body").addClass("active");
        jQuery(aPanel).addClass("active");
    }, function() {
        jQuery("body").removeClass("active");
        jQuery(aPanel).removeClass("active");
    });
```

Edit:

I have applied Overflow: Hidden; to the **page** element, but the element is still scrollable on both the y and x axis. I guess what I am really asking is how to disable scrolling through jQuery.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel your scroll event on the aPanel.

```
$(aPanel).on('scroll', function (event) {
    if ($(aPanel).hasClass('active')) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've done that, it doesn't stop the scroll functionality on a touch based device.

Comment: Oh now I got your question. I will update in a second with a different answer.

Comment: How would I apply this to the page element if the aPanel is active? I am sorry, I am no Javascript/jQuery master... I am trying to learn by doing and troubleshooting.

Comment: @AaronBrewer you attach it to the body instead of to aPanel :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but unfortunately it isn't disabling the scroll functionality. You can see the update at iamaaron.com/alpha . Thank you!

Comment: @AaronBrewer I inspected the scripts and I don't see the scroll event handler anywhere.

Comment: @AaronBrewer I cannot actually debug your application. Try attaching the event handler to the element that is scrolling. From what I can see it's the div with class page.

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```